# How to show the PrintDialog just after showing the preview in FastReport?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm using **Delphi** to develop a desktop database application, and I've an invoice report made with **FastReport**, I know that I can use `InvoiceReport.ShowReport` to show it's preview.
So I need to know how I can show the print dialog automatically just after showing the preview.
The user then can print it or cancel the dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show print dialog in Fast Report you simply call `Print` with `PrintOptions.ShowDialog:=True`. By default the preview form is shown modal, so the easiest solution is to change it and call `Print`:

```
InvoiceReport.PreviewOptions.Modal:=False;
InvoiceReport.PrintOptions.ShowDialog:=True;
InvoiceReport.ShowReport;
InvoiceReport.Print;
```

If you need to keep the preview form modal, the other option is to handle `OnPreview` event and call `Print`, but you have to postpone the procedure, so for example:

```
const 
  UM_PRINT_DIALOG = WM_USER+1;

...

procedure ShowPrintDialog(var Message: TMessage); message UM_PRINT_DIALOG;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InvoiceReport.ShowReport;
  //if you want to show the report once it is fully rendered use:
  //InvoiceReport.PrepareReport;
  //InvoiceReport.ShowPreparedReport;
end;

procedure TForm1.InvoiceReportPreview(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle,UM_PRINT_DIALOG,0,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowPrintDialog(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  InvoiceReport.PrintOptions.ShowDialog:=True;
  InvoiceReport.Print;
end;
```

Comment: The first solution was enough for me !

Answer (score -1):

Call `PrintDialog1.Execute` right after `InvoiceReport.ShowReport`.